# Hive: How to deal with files that comprise unfixed number of fields?

Tags: hadoop, hive

Dealing with a file on `HDFS` that comprises different num of fields separated by ','. For instance:

```
uid1, eid01, para1, para2, para3,para4,para5,timestamp
uid1, eid12, para56, para57, timestamp
uid3, eid42, para102,timestamp
```

The number of fields is not fixed.

Now I want to put these data into a `Hive` table that has 4 columns, and all fields of `'para..'` in one colume like:

```
  uid    eid              para                  datatime
  uid1  eid01  para1, para2, para3,para4,para5  timestamp
  uid1  eid12  para56, para57                   timestamp
  uid3  eid42  para102                          timestamp
```

The data amount is so large that I cannot deal with it using tools like `AWK`. Is there any other solution?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. create a temp hive table such as t_data_tmp(line string) , it has only one column. Load the data in hdfs file to t_data_tmp, per line will be one row.
2. create a hive table t_data with your schema, and insert overwrite t_data as select from t_data_tmp

when select form t_data_tmp, using hive functions for string(position, substr) to figure out value for each column(using the second comma and last comma as the splitter)

Comment: well thanks for your reply. I think `split()` and `reverse()` can achieve my target.